# How to wire switch with 8 gauge wire?

Tags: electrical, switch, wire

I want to connect 8 gauge wires to a 30 amp safety switch (http://smile.amazon.com/Leviton-3032-2W-Toggle-Double-Pole-Grounding/dp/B002MPPTBQ), but the wire is too thick to wrap around the screws on the switch. What's the best way to attach the wires to the switch?

(don't worry, they're on a 30 amp breaker in the panel)

Comment: Is this a 120v or 240v circuit? If you are using 240, then you will need to get a double pole switch.

Comment: I am, and it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 gauge wire should certainly fit on the screws; get a short bit of solid 10ga wire and pigtail that onto the switch.  10 gauge is legal for 30 amps, and a few inches of 10ga isn't going to defeat the purpose of running 8 gauge.

Comment: But then you'll need to enclose the 8-to-10 connection inside a box to meet code.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The switch also has to be in a box, so you'd just make up the pigtails in that same box.

Comment: Wire-nuts should suffice.

Comment: This worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either crimp-on cheap Fork or Ring Terminals or go to a budget blowing Switch Box.

[image: big wires little screws]

Comment: I was not able to locate a spade connector that was rated for 30A/8awg. Are these common?

Comment: I hadn't needed them for years (kitchen range),, but they were readily at my local Electrical Supply store & online places like Grainger have them (that's where I got the pics). There are also much bigger & thicker ones for car batteries & alternator setups or you can even use subpanel lugs from that side of things.